# What does "dhclient: bound to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" mean?

Tags: dhcp

So I am busy with a forensic research for my project, and came across this:

```
May 21 19:18:06 debian dhclient: bound to 91.199.30.100 -- renewal in 538 seconds.
```

I don't really know what it means with bound to "IP", can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the DHCP protocol (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt). Section 1.5 specifies exactly what is understood by "binding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network connections can (broadly speaking) be configured *statically*, meaning the connection parameters (such as IP address, netmask, gateway) are hard-coded in a configuration file; or they can be *dynamically* assigned by a remote server. For this, the [DHCP protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) was invented.

At the start of the dynamic configuration, the DHCP client broadcasts a message saying "Is there a DHCP server around? I need an IP address." If there is such a server on the network, it will announce itself, and a bit of negotiation takes place about which address exactly is available (the client may request the same address as the previous time, but that may not be available, etc.)

In the end, a *lease* is issued by the server to the client, meaning the client can use the address for a certain time (say 24 hours) before needing a refresh. The client then assigns the address to the proper network card, which is then said to be *bound* to the address.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it make it clear for me what it means, the only thing i dont understand is why it requests .1 but bounds to .100? May 21 19:52:59 debian dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 91.199.30.1 port 67
May 21 19:53:09 debian dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 91.199.30.1 port 67
May 21 19:53:22 debian dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 91.199.30.1 port 67
May 21 19:53:35 debian dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
May 21 19:53:35 debian dhclient: DHCPACK from 91.199.30.1
May 21 19:53:35 debian dhclient: bound to 91.199.30.100 -- renewal in 522 seconds.

Comment: @user889040 Your PC asks the DHCP server at `91.199.30.1` for an IP address and the DHCP server responds with _"here, take `91.199.30.100`!"_